# foreach() loop after MySQL query missing first record

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code, to split the resulting array up by the `Category` field.

```
    $query =    "SELECT * FROM livestock    
                WHERE   Category = 'monitor' 
                    OR  Category ='bearded' 
                    OR  Category ='chameleon' 
                    OR  Category ='skink' 
                    OR  Category ='small' 
                    OR  Category ='medium' 
                    OR  Category ='terrestrial'
                    OR  Category ='arboreal'
                    OR  Category ='leopard'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));        

    $rows = array();

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){            
            $rows[$row['Category']][] = $row;}
```

I then echo this out to the page in several places using the following code:

```
    foreach($rows['MONITOR'] as $row)
    {
        $commondraft = $row['Name'];
        $current = $row['Category'];

        if($current==$previous){
echo"<a href='/stocklist/".$row['id']."/".commonName($commondraft)."' class='row'>";        
        echo"<div class='common'>".$row['Name']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='descr'>".$row['Description']."</div>";
        echo"<div class='sex'>".$row['Sex']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='age'>".$row['Age']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='size'>".$row['Size']."</div>";  
        echo"<div class='origin'>".$row['Origin']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='scientific'>".$row['Scientific']."</div>"; 
        echo"<div class='prices'>".$row['Price']."</div>"; 

        echo"</a>";
        }
        $previous = $current;
        }
    echo"</div>";
```

But each time i echo this out using the `foreach()` loop it misses the first record.

How can i work a way around this and what's causing it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this because of `if($current==$previous)`? What is `$previous` set to at the start of the loop?

Comment: @Cyclone - you were right! The whole $current / $previous if() statement isnt required anymore since i split the array. it was from an old version of the code where i was splitting it by looking for the point at which the `Category` changed. So thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that this is caused by the following line in the loop:

```
if($current==$previous){
```

Since you only output a link if `$current` is equal to `$previous`, so the question is if you really initialize `$previous` correctly before your foreach loop. You will need to initialize `$previous` before the loop using something like this:

```
$previous = $rows['MONITOR'][0]['Category'];
```